# Display image on top of page in template part for displaying posts in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I am trying to add an image at the top of this template page. The page is tender-page.php where the tender is my post type.

Wherever I add an image it becomes part of the loop and is repeated but I just need to display it once at the top.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts in the loop
 *
 * @package
 */


$company = get_field( "company" );
$tender_documents = get_field( "tender_documents" );
$tender_category = get_field( "tender_category" );

?>

<div class="tender-listing">
... Content
</div>
```

Comment: I was editing the wrong file when adding the image. Edited the archive-tender.php which works.

Comment: If the issue is not related to the question you posted, consider deleting this question as this unlikely will ever help anyone in future.